# Minimum date form a oracle collection

Tags: oracle, collections, plsql

My collection is like:

```
TYPE ty_tb_v_cltbs_account_comp_sch 
    IS TABLE OF cltb_account_comp_sch%ROWTYPE 
    INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;

TYPE ty_cldaccnt IS RECORD ( 
    v_cltbs_account_comp_sch  ty_tb_v_cltbs_account_comp_sch);
```

From this collection I can access date values like `v_cltbs_account_comp_sch.due_date`

For all the values which are coming in the collection I want to get the minimum date out of `v_cltbs_account_comp_sch.due_date` using pl/sql block.

How can I do it?

Please help.

Comment: The best way you can do i to `order by asc` date the data which is populating the collection. And then you can always pick the first value of the collection which would be the least date

Comment: How are you populating the collection? With a SELECT ... BULK COLLECT statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something else to think about:

Create a collection index by string.

Loop through your collection with the dates and use that date as the index value in the string-indexed collection. The .FIRST index value when you are done is the minimum date.

I'm not saying this is the most optimal approach, but I like to remind developers about string-indexed associative arrays. You can do lots of interesting things with them.

```
CREATE TABLE temptab
(
   n   NUMBER,
   d   DATE
)
/

BEGIN
   FOR indx IN 1 .. 100
   LOOP
      INSERT INTO temptab
           VALUES (indx, TRUNC (SYSDATE, 'YYYY') + DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE (1, 365));
   END LOOP;

   COMMIT;
END;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE collections
IS
   TYPE rows_t IS TABLE OF temptab%ROWTYPE;

   TYPE dates_t IS TABLE OF NUMBER
      INDEX BY VARCHAR2 (100);
END;
/

DECLARE
   l_rows       collections.rows_t;
   l_dates      collections.dates_t;
   l_min_date   DATE;
BEGIN
   SELECT *
     BULK COLLECT INTO l_rows
     FROM temptab;

   FOR indx IN 1 .. l_rows.COUNT
   LOOP
      l_dates (TO_CHAR (l_rows (indx).d, 'YYYY-MM-DD')) := 0;
   END LOOP;

   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('min date = ' || l_dates.FIRST);
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to replicate te scenrio mentioned above. We can make some tweaks around looping and yeaah we get the output. Tis is not the most optimized code but it will work for small data sets. Hope this helps.

```
SET serveroutput ON;
DECLARE
type LV_OBJ
IS
  record
  (
    SR NUMBER,
    DT DATE );
type LV_DATE
IS
  TABLE OF LV_OBJ INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
  LV_TAB LV_DATE;
  LV_LEAST DATE;
  LV_VAR   VARCHAR2(1000);
BEGIN
  SELECT LEVEL,
    sysdate+level DT bulk collect
  INTO LV_TAB
  FROM DUAL
    CONNECT BY LEVEL < 10;
  FOR I IN LV_TAB.first..LV_TAB.last
  LOOP
    LV_VAR:=LV_VAR||','''||LV_TAB(I).DT||'''';
  END LOOP;
  EXECUTE immediate 'SELECT LEAST('||SUBSTR(LV_VAR,2,LENGTH(LV_VAR))||') FROM DUAL' INTO LV_LEAST;
  dbms_output.put_line(LV_LEAST);
END;
```

Comment: The array is an associative array and could be sparse - if this is the case you **cannot** loop from `FIRST` to `LAST`. Also, you really do not need dynamic SQL for this!

Comment: Yeaah i forgot to add to check if element at that index exists. Should have used EXISTS in this case to check

Comment: Yeaah agreed we dont need dynamic SQL in this case.

Comment: Using `EXISTS` with a `FOR` loop is not a good solution as you could have one element with the index `0` and another at index `1000000` then you will perform `1000001` iterations when you only need to perform `2` with the `NEXT` operator.

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE
  TYPE ty_tb_v_cltbs_account_comp_sch IS TABLE OF cltb_account_comp_sch%ROWTYPE INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
  TYPE ty_cldaccnt IS RECORD ( v_cltbs_account_comp_sch  ty_tb_v_cltbs_account_comp_sch);

  acct     ty_cldaccnt;
  min_date DATE;
  i        BINARY_INTEGER;
BEGIN
  -- Populate the record
  acct.v_cltbs_account_comp_sch(1).due_date := DATE '2017-05-01';
  acct.v_cltbs_account_comp_sch(7).due_date := DATE '2017-02-01';
  acct.v_cltbs_account_comp_sch(4).due_date := DATE '2017-04-01';

  -- Loop to find the minimum
  i := acct.v_cltbs_account_comp_sch.FIRST;
  WHILE i IS NOT NULL LOOP
    IF min_date IS NULL OR acct.v_cltbs_account_comp_sch(i).due_date < min_date THEN
      min_date := acct.v_cltbs_account_comp_sch(i).due_date;
    END IF;
    i := acct.v_cltbs_account_comp_sch.NEXT(i);
  END LOOP;

  -- Output the minimum
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( min_date );
END;
```